# How to re-initialize CANbus in case of an error at stm32f4 series

Tags: can

I have to set a scan program to re-init canbus in case of errors such as disconnection of Rx-Tx lines, or other errors types. When any error is solved, my program will detect and re-init. But are there any approaches to solve this problem ? I am open to any logical idea.

Comment: Normally you would simply force a MCU reset after a certain amount of errors, if feasible for the given application. Just re-initializing the CAN controller is typically (again, depending on which system you have) just about as "invasive" as a full reboot, since it might disturb a currently transmitted message on the bus.

Comment: @Lundin there is also streaming sound data must be stream cause of then i dont want to interrupt other tasks. I will try that first de-init & init can peripheral. But i couldn't  fall my mcu CAN error state yet, while i'm disconnecting Tx line. Cubemx CAN NVIC setups are not illustrative. There is an interrupt which is called SCE but there is no statement about what is its job in ref. manual and enabling this interrupt does not trigger CAN error callback.